# How can I create a submit form in Django with a dropping down list?

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, django-forms, html-select

I am just starting to work with Django and I have some problems with forms and dropping lists.

I have a model with two attributes, and I want to display one of the attributes in a dropping down list (this one will be unchangeable) and another one in a text field (this one will be changeable). Also, I have a submit button, so I want to change a second attribute in a text field and by pressing on the button. How can I do this? What would some examples be?

Comment: this could help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/

Comment: Hi Artem welcome to stackoverflow, Yes @olahsymbo is correct, you should refer to the documentation. You are specifically looking for `ChoiceField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield . Django Documentation is very well written you will find most of the solutions and examples there.I will try to answer this question with some examples so that you can fit in your logic and implement it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your helpful advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are starting to work with Django, you might or might not know about how Django handle forms.

In Django, forms can be handled in two ways:

1. User-created and managed forms (without any form class)
2. Class-managed forms (connected to Django models)

[Documentation form Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/)

Now let’s talk about the first type of forms (where you create your HTML form and *manage* the *request* sent to server):

These forms are simple to make and when there are only a few and are only suggested when you have a very small amount of inputs (I would say four or fewer *inputs*).

Here is a *simple* example of subscription of a newsletter with an email example.

```html
<form id='sub-form' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
         <input type="email" name="sub_email">
    </div>
    <input class="button" value="Subscribe" type="submit" id="subbutton">
</form>
```

So a very important thing to look at here is `{% csrf_token %}`, about which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and about how it works and prevents [cross-site request forgery](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). This token will be required when you make a request to Django server with any post request and data.

In this subscription form you see one `<input>` with `name="sub_email"`. Take note of this as we will use this to get this value on the server as this is the **`key`** to its **value**, and then a simple **Submit Button**.

When you press <kbd>Submit</kbd> on a page let’s say *url* = "**http://BASE_URL/home"** you will receive a **POST** request on the view that handles that URL.

So now coming to the `view.py`, let’s say you only allow registered users to subscribe then the view will go something like this (assuming you are not expecting any other request from the home URL).

```
def home(request):
    user=request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        if user.is_authenticated:
            email = request.POST['sub_email'] #Using name of input
            #Logic to save this email
            return HttpResponse("You are Subscribed",status=200)
        else:
            return HttpReposnse("You are not Authenticated",status=401)
    else:
        return render(request,"home.html")
```

Now as you are the expert of simple forms, let’s work with Django class-based forms.

---

These views are a little work when you have very few inputs, but they are a great help in manageability and when you have to work with large number of inputs.

> You will request these Class Based Forms as in your question you are trying to send an instance of a model from your `Models.py` to a form to user.

I have a model of Posts that can be used for this example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 90,null=True)
    subTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 160,null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 3,default = 'IN',null=True)
```

Now according to your question, you are trying to let the user change one attribute, let’s say `postTitle` and for location you are **not** letting the user select one of the countries which is preselected and for your post.

Now we have to create a form for this. Forms in class based are created in **Forms.py**. If you don't have **forms.py** then you can create one right along **models.py** and **views.py**.

[image: Forms.py]

Now for the form, I would like to edit some existing data as you are saying one of the attributes (Fields) is fixed and another editable, but you get the value from the model.

```
class PostEditForm(ModelForm):
    location = forms.CharField(label='Country ',widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'Classes_HERE','placeholder':' Select a Country','disabled':'disabled'} ,choices=country_list),required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= ['postTitle','subTitle','location']
        labels = {
            'postTitle':'Title',
            'subTitle':'Sub-Title',
        }
        widgets = {
            'postTitle': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mention_class_here','placeholder':' Add Title'}),
            'subTitle': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mention_class_here','placeholder':' Add Sub-Title'})
        }
```

Attributes can be mentioned in forms fields the way I have mentioned them in the above example. I used `disabled="disabled"` to **disable** (*not editable*) location field and used `forms.Select` to make it drop down.

You might also see that I gave the location field a list to choose from. This is how you can create a list of your items. It's been quite some time when I wrote this, so there might be errors or it may not work for you, so just make sure you are referring to the current documentation and searching Stack Overflow for answers.

```
country_list = [
    ('', 'Select a Country'),
    ("AF", "Afghanistan"),
    ("AX", "Aland Islands"),
    ("AL", "Albania"),
    ("DZ", "Algeria"),
    ("AS", "American Samoa"),
    ("AD", "Andorra"),
    ("AO", "Angola"),
    ("AI", "Anguilla"),
    ("AQ", "Antarctica"),
    ("AG", "Antigua And Barbuda"),
    ("AR", "Argentina"),
    ("AM", "Armenia"),
    ("AW", "Aruba"),
.
.
.
```

Now this form can be passed as context in a view to an HTML page.

```
def editPost(request,post_id):
    user=request.user
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id) #Getting the instance of Post
    if user.is_authenticated:
        formPost = PostEditForm(request.POST or None,instance=post)

        if request.method=='POST':
            if formPost.is_valid():
                    savedPost=formPost.save()
        else:
            return render(request,'postEdit.html',{'formPost':formPost})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not Authorized",status:401)
```

Now your HTML file *postEdit.html* should look something like this:

```html
<form id="post-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {{formPost}}
    </div>
</form>
```

That is it and adding a submit button in the same form, you can now edit your instance of `post` that you passed along with this `{{formPost}}`. Combine your logic wherever you think needs a change to fit in what you want to do.

By no means I am saying all this code is in working condition, but it is shown only to illustrate the flow and working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I do really appreciate it and find it very useful. That's exactly what I was looking for.